# No Transaction Data Returned From getItemSummariesForSite

Tags: yodlee

When I add a container based account for DagBank, using the following steps.

1. addItemForContentService1
2. startRefresh7
3. getItemSummaryForItem1

I get back transactions under ItemData>Accounts>BankTransactions

However if I follow the steps to add DagBank via the SiteBased approach, I get back no transactions.

1. addSiteAccount
2. startSiteRefresh
3. getItemSummariesForSite

So this is adding the same test bank account registered with the DagSystem https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/index.do

The XML Response I get back from getItemSummariesForSite is below, if this helps.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
<ns30:getItemSummariesForSiteResponse xmlns:ns30="http://dataservice.dataservice.core.soap.yodlee.com">
  <getItemSummariesForSiteReturn>
    <elements xmlns:ns6="http://common.soap.yodlee.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns6:ItemSummary">
      <itemId>10105227</itemId>
      <contentServiceId>11195</contentServiceId>
      <contentServiceInfo>
        <contentServiceId>11195</contentServiceId>
        <serviceId>0</serviceId>
        <contentServiceDisplayName>DagBank</contentServiceDisplayName>
        <organizationId>1148</organizationId>
        <organizationDisplayName>Demo Bank</organizationDisplayName>
        <siteId>8995</siteId>
        <siteDisplayName>DagBank</siteDisplayName>
        <custom>false</custom>
        <loginUrl>http://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/index.do</loginUrl>
        <homeUrl>http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do</homeUrl>
        <registrationUrl>http://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/index.do</registrationUrl>
        <passwordHelpUrl>http://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/index.do</passwordHelpUrl>
        <contactUrl>http://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/index.do</contactUrl>
        <containerInfo>
          <containerName>bank</containerName>
          <assetType>1</assetType>
        </containerInfo>
        <isCredentialRequired>true</isCredentialRequired>
        <autoRegistrationSupported>false</autoRegistrationSupported>
        <autoLoginType>1</autoLoginType>
        <geographicRegionsServed>
          <elements xsi:type="ns6:GeographicRegion_US">
            <country>US</country>
          </elements>
          <elements>
            <country>GLOBAL</country>
          </elements>
          <elements>
            <country>CA</country>
          </elements>
        </geographicRegionsServed>
        <autoPayCardSetupSupported>false</autoPayCardSetupSupported>
        <directCardPaymentSupported>false</directCardPaymentSupported>
        <directCheckPaymentSupported>false</directCheckPaymentSupported>
        <autoPayCardCancelSupported>false</autoPayCardCancelSupported>
        <paymentVerificationSupported>false</paymentVerificationSupported>
        <supportedAutoPaySetupCardTypeIds />
        <supportedDirectPaymentCardTypeIds />
        <hasPaymentHistory>false</hasPaymentHistory>
        <timeToUpdatePaymentHistory>-1</timeToUpdatePaymentHistory>
        <timeToPostDirectCardPayment>25200</timeToPostDirectCardPayment>
        <isCSCForDirectPaymRequired>false</isCSCForDirectPaymRequired>
        <isCSCForAutoPayRequired>false</isCSCForAutoPayRequired>
        <timeZoneId>America/New_York</timeZoneId>
        <isIAVFastSupported>true</isIAVFastSupported>
        <hasSiblingContentServices>false</hasSiblingContentServices>
        <isFTEnabled>true</isFTEnabled>
        <isOnlinePaymentSupported>false</isOnlinePaymentSupported>
        <autoRegistrationPaperBillSuppressionType>NOT_SUPPRESSED</autoRegistrationPaperBillSuppressionType>
        <autoPayCardPaperBillSuppressionType>NOT_SUPPRESSED</autoPayCardPaperBillSuppressionType>
        <directCardPaymentPaperBillSuppressionType>NOT_SUPPRESSED</directCardPaymentPaperBillSuppressionType>
        <addItemAccountSupported>false</addItemAccountSupported>
        <isAddAccountMultiFormAction>false</isAddAccountMultiFormAction>
        <isAutoRegistrationMultiFormAction>false</isAutoRegistrationMultiFormAction>
        <isAddItemAccountMultiFormAction>false</isAddItemAccountMultiFormAction>
        <isSiteCredentialsStored>true</isSiteCredentialsStored>
        <isPaymentAmountRequiredForAutopay>false</isPaymentAmountRequiredForAutopay>
        <isNumberOfPaymentsRequiredForAutopay>false</isNumberOfPaymentsRequiredForAutopay>
        <isFrequencyRequiredForAutopay>false</isFrequencyRequiredForAutopay>
        <supportedAutopayFrequencyTypes />
        <isConveninceFeeChargedForDirectCardPayment>false</isConveninceFeeChargedForDirectCardPayment>
        <conveninceFeeRuleMessage>(Canada)</conveninceFeeRuleMessage>
        <isEBillPaymSupprtd>false</isEBillPaymSupprtd>
        <isBetaSite>false</isBetaSite>
        <isBPAASource>false</isBPAASource>
        <isBPAADest>false</isBPAADest>
        <supportedBPSRecurringFrequencies />
        <checkLeadInterval>-1</checkLeadInterval>
        <cardLeadInterval>-1</cardLeadInterval>
        <isDirectTransferSupported>false</isDirectTransferSupported>
        <isSiblingAutoAdditionSafe>false</isSiblingAutoAdditionSafe>
        <defaultHelpText>11195</defaultHelpText>
      </contentServiceInfo>
      <itemDisplayName>DagBank</itemDisplayName>
      <refreshInfo>
        <itemId>10105227</itemId>
        <statusCode>0</statusCode>
        <refreshType>2</refreshType>
        <refreshRequestTime>0</refreshRequestTime>
        <lastUpdatedTime>1429862378</lastUpdatedTime>
        <lastUpdateAttemptTime>1429862378</lastUpdateAttemptTime>
        <itemAccessStatus>ACCESS_VERIFIED</itemAccessStatus>
        <userActionRequiredType>NONE</userActionRequiredType>
        <userActionRequiredCode>0</userActionRequiredCode>
        <userActionRequiredSince>2015-04-24T00:51:26.000-07:00</userActionRequiredSince>
        <lastDataUpdateAttempt>
          <date>2015-04-24T00:59:38.000-07:00</date>
          <status>SUCCESS</status>
          <statusCode>0</statusCode>
          <type>USER_REQUESTED</type>
        </lastDataUpdateAttempt>
        <lastUserRequestedDataUpdateAttempt>
          <date>2015-04-24T00:59:38.000-07:00</date>
          <status>SUCCESS</status>
          <statusCode>0</statusCode>
          <type>USER_REQUESTED</type>
        </lastUserRequestedDataUpdateAttempt>
        <lastSuccessfulDataUpdate>2015-04-24T00:59:38.000-07:00</lastSuccessfulDataUpdate>
        <itemCreateDate>2015-04-24T00:51:26.000-07:00</itemCreateDate>
        <nextUpdateTime>1429912235</nextUpdateTime>
        <responseCodeType>NONE</responseCodeType>
        <retryCount>0</retryCount>
        <refreshMode>NORMAL</refreshMode>
      </refreshInfo>
      <isCustom>false</isCustom>
      <isDisabled>false</isDisabled>
      <itemData>
        <accounts>
          <elements xmlns:ns21="http://types.dataservice.core.soap.yodlee.com" xsi:type="ns21:BankData">
            <cacheItemId>10105427</cacheItemId>
            <isItemAccountDeleted>0</isItemAccountDeleted>
            <accountId>10087068</accountId>
            <level>0</level>
            <accountDisplayName>
              <accountNames>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s737="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s737:string">SITE</key>
                  <value xmlns:s738="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s738:string">DagBank</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s739="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s739:string">ACCNAME_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s740="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s740:string">Personal Account</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s741="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s741:string">SITE_ACCNAME_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s742="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s742:string">DagBank - Personal Account</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s743="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s743:string">SITE_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s744="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s744:string">DagBank</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s745="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s745:string">SITE_ITEMNICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s746="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s746:string">DagBank</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s747="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s747:string">SITE_ACCNAME_NICKNAME_INLINE_PATT</key>
                  <value xmlns:s748="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s748:string">DagBank - Personal Account</value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s749="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s749:string">ACCNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s750="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s750:string">Personal Account</value>
                </table>
              </accountNames>
              <htmlFormattedAccountName>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s751="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s751:string">SITE</key>
                  <value xmlns:s752="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s752:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">&lt;strong>DagBank&lt;/strong>&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s753="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s753:string">ACCNAME_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s754="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s754:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">- Personal Account&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s755="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s755:string">SITE_ACCNAME_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s756="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s756:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">&lt;strong>DagBank&lt;/strong> - Personal Account&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s757="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s757:string">SITE_NICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s758="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s758:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">&lt;strong>DagBank&lt;/strong>&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s759="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s759:string">SITE_ITEMNICKNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s760="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s760:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">&lt;strong>DagBank&lt;/strong>&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s761="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s761:string">SITE_ACCNAME_NICKNAME_INLINE_PATT</key>
                  <value xmlns:s762="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s762:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">&lt;strong>DagBank&lt;/strong> - Personal Account&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <key xmlns:s763="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s763:string">ACCNAME</key>
                  <value xmlns:s764="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="s764:string">&lt;span class="{0}">&lt;a href= "{1}" title= "{2}">- Personal Account&lt;/a>&lt;/span></value>
                </table>
              </htmlFormattedAccountName>
              <SPANCLASS>acctbean</SPANCLASS>
            </accountDisplayName>
            <itemAccountId>10121523</itemAccountId>
            <baseTagDataId>BANK_ACCOUNT:10105427:0:10087068</baseTagDataId>
            <refreshTime>1429862378</refreshTime>
            <itemDataTableId>10</itemDataTableId>
            <itemAccountStatusId>1</itemAccountStatusId>
            <isTaxDeductible xsi:nil="1" />
            <isBusinessExpense xsi:nil="1" />
            <isMedicalExpense xsi:nil="1" />
            <isReimbursable xsi:nil="1" />
            <includeInNetworth>1</includeInNetworth>
            <isAsset xsi:nil="1" />
            <defTxnCategoryId xsi:nil="1" />
            <isLinkedItemAccount>false</isLinkedItemAccount>
            <categoryLevelId xsi:nil="1" />
            <isUpdatePastTransaction>false</isUpdatePastTransaction>
            <isUpdateTxCategory>true</isUpdateTxCategory>
            <createOpeningTxn>true</createOpeningTxn>
            <isSeidFromDataSource>1</isSeidFromDataSource>
            <isSeidMod>0</isSeidMod>
            <acctTypeId>3</acctTypeId>
            <acctType>checking</acctType>
            <localizedAcctType>fixedDeposit</localizedAcctType>
            <srcElementId>23232323</srcElementId>
            <individualInformationId xsi:nil="1" />
            <bankAccountId>10087068</bankAccountId>
            <isDeleted>0</isDeleted>
            <lastUpdated>1429862378</lastUpdated>
            <hasDetails>0</hasDetails>
            <interestRate xsi:nil="1" />
            <accountNumber>xxxx3xxx</accountNumber>
            <accountHolder>John Thompson</accountHolder>
            <tranListToDate />
            <tranListFromDate />
            <availableBalance>
              <amount>754.78</amount>
              <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
            </availableBalance>
            <currentBalance>
              <amount>644.78</amount>
              <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
            </currentBalance>
            <accountName>Personal Account</accountName>
            <annualPercentYield xsi:nil="1" />
            <maturityDate />
            <asOfDate />
            <isPaperlessStmtOn>0</isPaperlessStmtOn>
            <created>1429861899</created>
          </elements>
        </accounts>
      </itemData>
      <itemStatus>0</itemStatus>
      <isHeld>0</isHeld>
      <isSharedItem>false</isSharedItem>
      <isPrepop>false</isPrepop>
      <memSiteAccId>10063351</memSiteAccId>
    </elements>
  </getItemSummariesForSiteReturn>
</ns30:getItemSummariesForSiteResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting transactions (irrespective of which approach you are using- container based or site based) you should use [executeUserSearchRequest](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) API.

getItemSummariesForSite provides account level details not the transactions.